# Ionic Cordova Badge Cart Number

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on a shopping cart using `cordova` and `ionic` and I have some questions:

How can I get total item cart to badge in ionic?

I've try with the following `code`:

**Ionic badge**:

```
ng-model="data.badgeCount"
```

**Controller**:

```
$scope.data = {
  badgeCount : 2
}
```

and it works well, but when I change it to:

```
ng-model="{{total_qty}}"
```

it gives me an error. Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your question is unclear, but `ngModel` directive works **without** *interpolation*:

```
ng-model="total_qty"
```